# itext merging in running report

Tags: pdf, merge, itext

Hiyas

We create a PDF using Chunks and Phrases and DirectContent, etc. with a PdfWriter(Document combination. So far this works finely. Whilst the PDF is being created at some spaces I need to merge in pages from another PDF. So far I'm doing this by keeping a list of files to merge and merge them together at the end of the actual report (by closing that report, reopening the report with a PdfCopy and merge in the files at the corresponding pages).

This works fine too, so far, but it has a major drawback: if the report is larger (say, 1800 pages) and needs to merge like 1000 PDF's into that PDF, it gets really, really slow. I guess this has to do with the fact that the main PDF needs to be rewritten because the PDF to merge into the main document is not just simply merged at the end of the main report, but somewhere deep within and this is being repeated for the other 999 PDF's to merge.

So I thought about speeding this a little up and import the page while I'm still creating the report using PdfWriter.getImportedPage() and adding this as template into the PDF. This works fine, but after reading "How not to merge documents" (http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents-itext5/how-not-merge-documents) I'm not so sure anymore wether this is actually a good solution.

However.. I also don't really know any better way other than merging when the main report has finished and this, really, is very slow with hundreds of PDF?s to merge.

So is using PdfWriter.getImportedPage() and rotating the page accordingly a good idea or rather a bad idea? Or is there any alternative that I don't know?

Comment: Are you writing the PDF to file each time? It may speed up if you keep it in memory and only write it to file at the end.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse We cannot keep it in memory as we don't know how large it will be and the chance to run out of memory is higher than the performance gain we could get. Running out of memory on an application server is generally not a good idea, so we would need to keep it as an external process and run it like that but we shied away from that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is using PdfWriter.getImportedPage() and rotating the page accordingly a good idea or rather a bad idea?

It depends. ;)

It depends on what is important in your use case. In general:

- If in your resulting document you want to have the pages appear exactly as they do in their respective original document, then use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy`, this is *definitively the better choice*.
- If your original pages have annotations (e.g. AcroForm form fields visualizations) you want to also have in your result document, then use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy`, this is *definitively the better choice* in this case, too.
- Otherwise using `PdfWriter` and `addTemplate(...getImportedPage(...), ...)` *might be an acceptable or even good choice.*

> Or is there any alternative that I don't know?

There might be optimizations which you had not applied to your `PdfCopy` solution but there are no conceptually different options in iText 5.